# SocketAsyncEventArgs with binary/byte[] streams

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, socketasynceventargs

I'm new to C# and sockets so I apologize if my questions are out of line.  I started building a socket interface using the example in this link:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/High-Performance-NET-69c2df2f

I want to be able to transfer binary files across the socket so I made an assumption (maybe the wrong one) that I should not use `StringBuilder`.  I changed the `OSUserToken` from the original to use a `MemoryStream` and `BinaryWriter` (commenting out the original code).

Elsewhere in the code (from the link above), `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is intialized with `SetBuffer(new Byte[_bufferSize], 0, _bufferSize);`.  I'm concerned this will not mesh well with my `MemoryStream` and `BinaryWriter` but it seems to work.

```
sealed class UserToken : IDisposable
{
    private Socket _ownerSocket;
    public Socket ownerSocket { get { return _ownerSocket; } }

    private MemoryStream _memoryStream;
    private BinaryWriter _binaryWriter;
    //private StringBuilder stringbuilder;

    private int totalByteCount;

    public String LastError;

    public UserToken(Socket readSocket, int bufferSize)
    {
        _ownerSocket = readSocket;
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        _binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(_memoryStream);
        //stringbuilder = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);
    }

    // Do something with the received data, then reset the token for use by another connection.
    // This is called when all of the data have been received for a read socket.
    public void ProcessData(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
    {
        String received = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_memoryStream.ToArray());
        //String received = stringbuilder.ToString();

        Debug.Write("Received: \"" + received + "\". The server has read " + received.Length + " bytes.");

        _memoryStream.SetLength(0);
        //stringbuilder.Length = 0;
        totalByteCount = 0;
    }

    public bool ReadSocketData(SocketAsyncEventArgs readSocket)
    {
        int byteCount = readSocket.BytesTransferred;

        /*
        if ((totalByteCount + byteCount) > stringbuilder.Capacity)
        {
            LastError = "Receive Buffer cannot hold the entire message for this connection.";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
        */
            //stringbuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readSocket.Buffer, readSocket.Offset, byteCount));
            _binaryWriter.Write(readSocket.Buffer,readSocket.Offset,byteCount);
            totalByteCount += byteCount;
            return true;
        /*}*/
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _memoryStream.Dispose();
        _binaryWriter.Dispose();
        try
        {
            _ownerSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Nothing to do here, connection is closed already
        }
        finally
        {
            _ownerSocket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, it seems to work without an issue.  Even if I set the `protected const int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1` it will accept a stream of >1 bytes:

```
17:11:20:433 - Debug - Initializing the listener on port 5000...
17:11:20:439 - Debug - Starting the listener...
17:11:20:444 - Debug - Server started.
17:11:31:856 - Debug - Received: "listener". The server has read 8 bytes.
17:11:33:264 - Debug - Received: "l". The server has read 1 bytes.
17:11:33:268 - Debug - Received: "istener". The server has read 7 bytes.
17:11:36:744 - Debug - Received: "l". The server has read 1 bytes.
17:11:36:744 - Debug - Received: "i". The server has read 1 bytes.
17:11:36:746 - Debug - Received: "stener". The server has read 6 bytes.
```

My questions are these:

1. Am I right that `StringBuilder` wouldn't work for binary files and I should use `MemoryStream` and `BinaryWriter`?
2. Do I need to be concerned with a buffer overflow if elsewhere in the program, the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is initialized with `SetBuffer(new Byte[_bufferSize], 0, _bufferSize);`?
3. If I have to obey the buffer size limitation, do I need to put the same buffer restriction on my client sending data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answers to my questions

1. `StringBuilder` works fine.  Just encode the strings in `base64` before sending and decode after receiving.  This should be done no matter if sending text or binary data. See the class I wrote below.
2. Still don't know the answer to this question but seeing as `StringBuilder` 
   & `base64` works with binary, this question is no longer relevant.
3. I think the answer to this question is yes.  The client should have a max message length.  I'm controlling based on the header portion of my socket where I define the length of the message.  The header is fixed length and my max message length is `0xFFFFF`.

Class for encoding/decoding base64:

```
public static class Base64
{
    public static string EncodeBase64(string text)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
    }

    public static string EncodeBase64(byte[] array)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(array);
    }

    public static string DecodeBase64ToString(string base64String)
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
    }

    public static Byte[] DecodeBase64ToBinary(string base64String)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```